# Image Slider w/ Unique URLs based on on Wordpress Image ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields

OK so I am building a custom Wordpress theme for a client which has a large image slider as part of the design.  What I need to do is allow each slide to have it's own URL (so people can link direct to the slide), and for that ID to be the wordpress image/media ID.  I'm using a repeater field in ACF if that makes any difference to my options.

I'm currently using Slick Slider with the "initialSlide" option but that a) doesn't change he URL as you flick through the gallery, and b) just uses numbers from 1 - whatever based on the images position in that slider.  I need this to be the WP image ID rather than its position, as its position could change if the clients shuffles the order of the items in the slider.

So i guess i'm looking for unique slide URLs something like http://www.whatever.com/slider/?slide=345 where 354 is the WP image ID, and where the URL actually changes as you click left/right.

Any ideas how this might be implemented?  I'm not looking for a WP plugin, just the JavaScript.

**Edit:** I just noticed I had the jQuery version of MasterSlider laying around and that does the dynamic URL tracking/deeplinking that i want but still just uses the position of the slide within the slider as the URL id.  Looking at the code I cannot figure out how to modify this to pass the ID from ACF image array instead.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well in case anyone else stumbles across this looking for the same answer, "MightySlider" did exactly what I needed.  Has deeplinking and also allows me to define a variable as the slide ID to be used in the URL that is created.